# Get the order total shipping in Woocommerce 3

Tags: php, wordpress, methods, woocommerce, orders

I'm trying to get the shipping method or cost of shipping for a WooCommerce order - I'm writing a custom email template that is different depending on free delivery vs paid delivery.

I found a function called `get_total_shipping()`, but this is now deprecated and I cannot find a replacement - does one exist?

I've noticed that the shipping amount is stored in a hidden meta field (`_order_shipping`), which I can access, but I worry that this might break on future WooCommerce updates.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Since Woocommerce 3 [`get_total_shipping()` method is replaced by `get_shipping_total()`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Abstract_Legacy_Order.html#560-567) .

So there is actually 2 available [CRUD getters](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/CRUD-Objects-in-3.0) methods for **shipping totals** in [**`WC_Abstract_Order`**](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Abstract_Order.html#_get_shipping_total) Class that can be used on the [**`WC_Order`**](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Order.html) instance object:

- `get_shipping_total()` that is the shipping total excluding taxes
- `get_shipping_tax()` that is the shipping taxes total

So you will use them with the `$order` variable object simply this way:

```
$shipping_total = $order->get_shipping_total();
$shipping_tax   = $order->get_shipping_tax();
```

There is also [**`get_shipping_to_display()`**](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Abstract_Order.html#1653-1693) method that will output the formatted shipping total.